# Mockito unable to mock ThreadLocalRandom

Tags: powermockito

I am trying to mock **ThreadLocalRandom** in my JUnit test.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {

    List<Game> games;

    @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(ThreadLocalRandom.class);
        when(ThreadLocalRandom.current()).thenReturn(any(ThreadLocalRandom.class));
        when(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(1);
       games = Arrays.asList(new Game1(), new Game2());
   }

   @PrepareForTest({ ThreadLocalRandom.class })
   @Test
   public void someTestName() {
       assertTrue(new Game(games).winner().equals(new Game1()));
   }
}
```

While running the test I am getting error like,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

Any input how to solve this?

```
public class Toss {

    private final List<Game> games;

    public Toss(List<Game> games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public Game winner() {
        return games.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(games.size()));
    }
}
```

Any input what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
when(ThreadLocalRandom.current()).thenReturn(any(ThreadLocalRandom.class));
```

makes no sense.  You can't tell Mockito (or PowerMock) to return just any old `ThreadLocalRandom` that it likes.  You need to tell it which object to return.  So instantiate `ThreadLocalRandom` and use the object that you create after `thenReturn`.

Comment: **ThreadLocalRandom** is a static class which has private constructor. `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` returns an ThreadLocalRandom instance. So for this, creating an object with New won't work. Any suggestion on that front?

Comment: So if the only way to make a `ThreadLocalRandom` is with `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`, why do you think you need to stub this method?